# Google Cloud, is it normal for Wordpress(click to deploy) install running more than 30 min?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have problem previously with my WordPress, so I delete that one and re-install another one using the same "Click to deploy Wordpress". But the installing time is longer than before and still running after 50 min. The website seems up but the information part(password, phpMyadmin password..etc) doesn't come out. So I create another project to try again, still running.

Is there something wrong with my setting? or is because I delete and re-install too many times? or what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

For other community members that are not yet aware, there is currently an [opened report](https://issuetracker.google.com/69098399).

A workaround was posted in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193060/google-cloud-is-it-normal-for-wordpressclick-to-deploy-install-running-more-t).

Update: This issue was fixed a couple of days ago.